# How to modify Firefox default search engine url without getting hands dirty

Tags: firefox, search, search-engines

I'd like to adjust default firefox search engine's URI by replacing `www` with `enrypted`. How can I achieve that without getting hands dirty with firefox extensions or addons? I want just open text editor and replace one subline with another.

Answer (score 0):

New versions of Firefox doesn't store the search engines in a text/XML file that you could edit with a text editor like versions of a few years ago.

You best option may be using an addon for creating custom search engines to the search bar like [Search Engine Creator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-engine-creator/), create a new entry for https://encrypted.google.com/ and set it as default search engine.